# Fetching json data from external MySQL server (via a PHP script) in android

Tags: android, json, jdbc

I am fetching json data from external MySQL server in android application and displaying that data in a list-view.

But even when json data is very less and internet connection is good,it takes a little bit more time than expected.Is there any way to improve this speed? Or is there a better way than this to fetch data from external server(For ex. using JDBC)?

The Json Fetcher and parser code which I am currently using is -

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent(); 

try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
```

Comment: can you add the code you're using to retrieve the JSON?

Comment: @D4nC00per - I have added the code which I am using

Comment: Have you seen if there is any difference in the time taken when requesting from a web browser?

Comment: have you tried fetching data by other tools? does response time differ? it could be the server which processes the request slowly. Basically, you won't notice any difference in response time whether you use DefaultHttpClient, AndroidHttpClient, HttpUrlConnection or whatever; whether you read char by char or into a buffer, etc. with data of small size (measured in kilobytes)

Comment: I have not tried by other methods but I have conducted some online coding contests on that server for 100 people at a time and server was quite fast so I guess it's not a server problem.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is any faster method to fetch json data

Comment: It seems as though you're doing it the correct way imo